# how to include json file in our page using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Can you please tell me how to include json file in our project in the same way that we include js and css files. Actually I am making a example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf8" />
<title>jQuery i18n Plugin</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.i18n.min.js"></script>

<script  type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    i18n_dict = {
        "Example 1"  : "teiän veen",
        "Example 2"  : "tei'än ve'en",
        "Example 3"  : "teiä vede",
        "Example 4"  : "teirän veren",
        "Example 5"  : "teilän velen",
        "Example 6"  : "teijjän vejen",
        "Example 7"  : "teidän veden",
        "Example 8"  : "teitän veten",
        "Example 9"  : "teiðän veðen",
        "Example 10" : "teidhän vethen",
        "Dynamic Content" : "Your browser window is %s x %s",
        "Ordered Dynamic Content": "%2$s is the height of your browser window, and %1$s is the width."
    };

    $.i18n.setDictionary(i18n_dict);

    $('input#translate_button').click( function(event) {
        $('div#example1').text($.i18n._('Example 1'));
        $('div#example2').text($.i18n._('Example 2'));
        $('div#example3').text($.i18n._('Example 3'));
        $('div#example4').text($.i18n._('Example 4'));
        $('div#example5').text($.i18n._('Example 5'));
        $('div#example6').text($.i18n._('Example 6'));
        $('div#example7').text($.i18n._('Example 7'));
        $('div#example8').text($.i18n._('Example 8'));
        $('div#example9').text($.i18n._('Example 9'));
        $('div#example10').text($.i18n._('Example 10'));
        $('div#dynamic').text($.i18n._('Dynamic Content', [$(document).width(), $(document).height()]));
        $('div#orderedDynamic').text($.i18n._('Ordered Dynamic Content', [$(document).width(), $(document).height()]));
    });
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        font-size: 30px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    input {
        font-size: 30px;
    }
    p {
        font-size: 17px;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <p>
        Click the button to translate the following text into some random Finnish from the
        <a href='http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finnish_phonology'>Wikipedia Finnish Phonology Article</a>
    </p>

    <div id='example1'>Example 1</div>
    <div id='example2'>Example 2</div>
    <div id='example3'>Example 3</div>
    <div id='example4'>Example 4</div>
    <div id='example5'>Example 5</div>
    <div id='example6'>Example 6</div>
    <div id='example7'>Example 7</div>
    <div id='example8'>Example 8</div>
    <div id='example9'>Example 9</div>
    <div id='example10'>Example 10</div>
    <div id='dynamic'>Dynamic Content</div>
    <div id='orderedDynamic'>Ordered Dynamic Content</div>

    <input type='button' id='translate_button' value='Internationalize!' />
</body>
</html>
```

Instead of that I need to add in other json file

```
"Example 1"  : "teiän veen",
            "Example 2"  : "tei'än ve'en",
            "Example 3"  : "teiä vede",
            "Example 4"  : "teirän veren",
            "Example 5"  : "teilän velen",
            "Example 6"  : "teijjän vejen",
            "Example 7"  : "teidän veden",
            "Example 8"  : "teitän veten",
            "Example 9"  : "teiðän veðen",
            "Example 10" : "teidhän vethen",
```

Can you please tell me how to do?

Comment: [Don't reinvent the wheel](http://i18next.com/) : ))

Comment: What about `$.getJSON("url", function(d){//stuff here})`…?

Answer (score 0):

You can just put it into js file the same way you do it in `<script>` tag (assigning your json object to a variable), and then import that js file with `<script src='...'></script>`.

Comment: actually I saw somewhere there is 3 file english french , hindi.when user change the janguage it show text in that langusge

Comment: is this possible in jquerry

Comment: Are you detecting language on client-side or server-side? If server, then you can make different files for languages and just put needed `script` tag. If on client, you'll need to import all of them, or as showed in other answers, use `getJSON`

Comment: Actually One of my friend use i18n plugin .in which he make 3 json file and import that .then when it change language it change the text which is display (same language).

Comment: From morning I am looking that type of example can we make that type of example on fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
$('input#translate_button').click( function(event) {
                 $.getJSON('/yourjsonfile.json', function(i18n_dict){
                   $('div#example1').text(i18n_dict.Example1);
                   $('div#example2').text(i18n_dict.Example2);
                   $('div#example3').text(i18n_dict.Example3);
                   $('div#example4').text(i18n_dict.Example4);
                   $('div#example5').text(i18n_dict.Example5);
                   $('div#example6').text(i18n_dict.Example6);
                   $('div#example7').text(i18n_dict.Example7);
                   $('div#example8').text(i18n_dict.Example8);
                   $('div#example9').text(i18n_dict.Example9);
                   $('div#example10').text(i18n_dict.Example10);
                   $('div#dynamic').text(i18n_dict.DynamicContent, [$(document).width(), $(document).height()]);
                   $('div#orderedDynamic').text(i18n_dict.OrderedDynamicContent, [$(document).width(), $(document).height()]);

                 });

      });
```